# The layout of the view is not hiding properly using Height Constraint in IOS objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, height

I'm hiding and showing my view by modifying the height constraint. As you can see below

[image]

So I tried the same step for two of my views. One view hides properly but other one doesn't hide properly. This is the screenshot of layout of view which **hides properly**

[image]

These are the constraints of the Layout:

[image]

[image]

This is the code which is used to hide and show the view which **hides properly**

```
- (IBAction)NFASnewclick:(id)sender {
    if(_NFASFormB.isOn)
    {
        self.FormHeightConstraint.constant=0.0;
         NSLog(@"Hide Form");
    }
    else
    {
        self.FormHeightConstraint.constant=270;
         NSLog(@"show form");
    }
}
```

This is the screenshot of layout of view which **doesn't hides properly**

[image]

These are the constraints of the Layout:

[image]

[image]

This is the code which is used to hide and show the view which **does not hide properly**

```
- (IBAction)NFASoldclick:(id)sender {
    if(_NFASDD.isOn)
    {
        self.view1heightConstraints.constant=0.0;
       // [self.view1 setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        NSLog(@"HIDE layout");
    }
    else
    {
         self.view1heightConstraints.constant=730;
       // [self.view1 setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        NSLog(@"show layout");
    }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code. Because its exactly same as the view which is hiding properly. Maybe there is some problem with the constraint of the view. Which is hiding the view but brings big spaces. No clue how to fix that.

Comment: it might be happen due to conflict of constrain when you change self.view1heightConstraints.constant=0.0, you can check conflict by changing constrain constant value from storyboard.  you can set  priority value to resolve conflict.

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya do you mean changing the priority value 1000 to something else?

Comment: Did you get conflict?

Comment: change Priority (750) of constrain which is conflicted with heigh constrain

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya I changed the priority to 750 for the height constraint which is conflicting but still it didn't work.

Comment: Do not change priority of height it should be 1000. but need to change priority of bottom constrain

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya do u mean bottom space to constraint of view which is not getting hidden properly?

Comment: I have set the priority to 750 for the bottom space to constraint of view which is not getting hidden properly but that didn't work.